# how to resolve min/max width error domp while generating pdf?

Tags: php, html, web, pdf-generation, dompdf

i'm getting the following error in my code while converting to pdf

there's no inline block statement included and width is defined for every table header still issue is persistent

```
<?php
//print_invoice.php
if(isset($_GET["pdf"]) && isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    require_once 'pdf.php';
    include('connection2.php');
    $output = '';
    $statement = $connect->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM POrder
  WHERE order_id = :order_id
  LIMIT 1
 ");
    $statement->execute(
    array(
        ':order_id'       =>  $_GET["id"]
    )
);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $output .= '
   <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center" style="font-size:18px"><b>Invoice</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
    <td width="65%">
     To,<br />
     <b>Vendors Name</b><br />
     Name : '.$row["vendorname"].'<br />
     Description : '.$row["description"].'<br />
    </td>
    <td width="35%">
     Reverse Charge<br />
     Invoice No. : '.$row["order_no"].'<br />
     Invoice Date : '.$row["order_date"].'<br />
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <th>Sr No.</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Actual Amt.</th>
    <th colspan="2">GST (%)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Amt.</th>
   </tr>';
    $statement = $connect->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM POrder_item
   WHERE order_id = :order_id"
       );
        $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':order_id'       =>  $_GET["id"]
        )
    );
    $item_result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($item_result as $sub_row)
    {
            $count++;
            $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$count.'</td>
    <td>'.$sub_row["item_name"].'</td>
<td>'.$sub_row["item_quantity"].'</td>
<td>'.$sub_row["item_price"].'</td>
<td>'.$sub_row["item_price_bt"].'</td>
<td>'.$sub_row["item_gst"].'</td>
<td>'.$sub_row["item_price_at"].'</td>
    <td>'.$sub_row["final_amount"].'</td>
   </tr>
   ';
        }
        $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td align="right" colspan="11"><b>Total</b></td>
   <td align="right"><b>'.$row["total_after_tax"].'</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="11"><b>Total Amt. Before Tax :</b></td>
   <td align="right">'.$row["total_before_tax"].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="11">Add : GST :</td>
   <td align="right">'.$row["gst"].'</td>
  </tr>
   <td colspan="11"><b>Total Tax Amt.  :</b></td>
   <td align="right">'.$row["order_total_tax"].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="11"><b>Total Amt. After Tax :</b></td>
   <td align="right">'.$row["total_after_tax"].'</td>
  </tr>

  ';
    $output .= '
      </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   ;
    }
    $pdf = new Pdf();
    $file_name = 'Invoice-'.$row["order_no"].'.pdf';
    $pdf->loadHtml($output);
    $pdf->render();
    $pdf->stream($file_name, array("Attachment" => false));
}
?>
```

// pdf.php

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf extends Dompdf{
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
}
?>
```

i expect to get a pdf but instead i get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dompdf\Exception' with message
>   'Min/max width is undefined for table rows' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/TableRow.php:72
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(903):
>   Dompdf\FrameReflower\TableRow->get_min_max_width() #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/AbstractFrameReflower.php(268):
>   Dompdf\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator->get_min_max_width() #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(903):
>   Dompdf\FrameReflower\AbstractFrameReflower->get_min_max_width() #3
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/AbstractFrameReflower.php(268):
>   Dompdf\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator->get_min_max_width() #4
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(903):
>   Dompdf\FrameReflower\AbstractFrameReflower->get_min_max_width in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NTPC/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/TableRow.php
>   on line 72

Comment: Which dompdf version are you using?

Comment: @digijay i'm using an older version 0.8.2, but i also tried with the current stable version 0.8.3 but i get exact same results

Comment: in "pdf.php" file i removed the line containing autoload.in.php as it's no longer available in new library. then i get the error "Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that including dompdf like you do is no longer supported, [see issue 1153](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1153#issuecomment-198947599). The guy who's asking gets exactly the same error messages as you do.

I'd recommend to follow the [dompdf installation manual](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#easy-installation) and install it with composer (as it is imo thyoue most hassle-free way in the long term). I've also found something on [installing composer on XAMPP](https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/install-composer-windows-xampp/), but I can't really help with this since I don't know XAMPP. As a fallback you could download a pre-configured package (described some lines below).

And also cheack the [quick start tutorial](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start) to see if dompdf genereally works instead of using your own code first, because some of it might be deprecated.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: thanks for the help mate! i updated the deprecated code and installed composer. The uncaught exception error was still there, which i reolved using $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true); as there were some structural errors in my html tables.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not apply display property to your table (not in inline styles or external styles).**

Found from web:

In this case, the fix ended up being pretty simple, it didn’t like the inline style `display:block;` that I had added to the table. 
Upon a little more testing, I found that it would allow for `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;`.

This makes sense as a table has natively the property `display:table;` and I think block is probably not really valid (although works fine in browsers, is a neat trick to apply to td elements to create a responsive table, and didn’t generate any warnings during validation.

Comment: Could you please link the original page ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to downgrade dompdf to 1.0.0

Am not saying it's the best solution but as for now with it was not depending on so many other packages but as it comes with phenx/php-svg-lib and phenx/php-font-lib those were also downgraded.

And also the downside of this is that it was installed in the main packages in composer.json

Note: This will upgrade, downgrade and remove  packages currently locked to specific versions of the dompdf/dompdf:1.0.0

The command I used is `composer require dompdf/dompdf:1.0.0 -w`

Answer (score 0):

For me @Ghazni Ali had the right cause.
Adding any type of display to a table made this error occur.

I was trying to get my elements properly spaced and inline.

What I found was I had to add width to my table and then add additional widths to the td inside of the table.

Below is trying to get a 20% and 80% split.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20% !important; border: 1px solid black;">
        <p >Left Test</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid black;">
        <p >Right Test</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried similar methods with using a div tag but it wouldn't appear correct.
The first example is with the table and the bottom two are with div tags.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the problem vas html syntax instead  was  after fixing problem solved